# Implementing a File class

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-3.x, file

I studying for a Python course. I was finished working on task about creating a file class which can read, write lines to file. This class also needs magic methods (`__add__`, `__str__`, `__iter__`, `__next__`)

Can you review code and give a tip about improvements using the DRY principle (for example, how avoid to copy/paste with `open`).

```
from tempfile import gettempdir
from os import path
import uuid


class File():

    def __init__(self, file_path):
       self.file_path = file_path
       self.current_position = 0

    def __iter__(self):
       return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:    
            with open(self.file_path, 'r') as f:
                f.seek(self.current_position)
                line = f.readline().strip()
                if not line:
                    self.current_position = 0
                    raise StopIteration('EOF')
                self.current_position = f.tell()
                return line
        except IOError:
            return 'Cant read next line'

    def write(self, line):
        try:
            with open(self.file_path, 'w') as file_obj:
                file_obj.write(line)
        except IOError as err:
            return 'Cant write to file: {0}'.format(err)

    def read(self):
        try:
            with open(self.file_path, 'r') as file_obj:
                return file_obj.read().strip()
        except IOError:
            return ''

    def __add__(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, File):
            tmp_file_path = path.join(gettempdir(), str(uuid.uuid4()))
            tmp_file = File(tmp_file_path)
            tmp_file.write(self.read() + '\n' + obj.read())
            return tmp_file

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file_path


f_obj = File('somepath1')
f_obj2 = File('somepath2')
f_obj3 = f_obj + f_obj2
for line in f_obj:
    print(line)
print(f_obj3.read())
```

Comment: Is there some reason you want to keep opening and closing the file again and again, instead of keeping it open?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`__iter__` and `__next__`**

Instead of re-opening the file each time and seeking to the previous position, you could write `__iter__` as a generator function by using `yield` instead of needing to define `__next__`. Something like:

```
def __iter__(self):
    with open(file) as f:
        yield from f
```

**Error handling**

In case of error, you're returning a string `'Cant read next line'`.
What if you have a file that contains text `'Cant read next line'`? How do you differentiate between these?

Well... you can't.

Instead of returning a string, throw an exception on error - that's what exceptions are meant for.

Also, this error message of yours isn't really correct. You most likely get IOError when opening a file... before even attempting to read first line from it.

It seems like your error handling code doesn't really do anything very useful with the IOError. So why not instead just let it bubble upwards and drop the try-catch block completely.

**Duplication**

You can define your own open method, so you don't have to repeat passing the file_path to it:

```
def open(self, mode='r'):
    open(self.file_path, mode)
```

You could also investigate writing you own [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) for opening the file [with](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) your custom error handling.

Comment: The answer is more than complete. Thank you! Now I know how to improve the code and learn the best practices.

Comment: Your `__iter__` yields just a single line. Don't you want `yield from f`?

Comment: Good point. I've updated the example.